# Applying string to ticks along X axis

Tags: plotting, ticks

I need to plot a dataset with the x-axis ticks as character (String) instead of conventional number. How can I do it?
Here is my data and code:

```
data={{"V", 61.5969, 33.626}, {"Y", 56.9077, 39.7866}, {"P", 62.9692, 
     31.8801}, {"V", 61.6344, 33.466}, {"D", 53.2597, 42.799}, {"L", 
     54.199, 42.8786}, {"S", 56.8791, 65.2661}, {"K", 54.5083, 
     35.1462}, {"V", 61.5614, 32.4005}, {"T", 61.4146, 71.286}, {"S", 
     57.6121, 65.6026}, {"K", 55.2787, 34.7415}, {"C", 56.9249, 
     30.3367}, {"G", 46.4798, 0}, {"S", 58.0113, 64.6901}, {"G", 45.4069,
     0}, {"N", 53.8871, 37.5137}, {"I", 60.7843, 39.2903}, {"E", 55.043,
     32.5105}, {"V", 60.7334, 34.5962}, {"K", 55.5029, 34.9302}, {"S", 
     57.475, 65.4979}, {"E", 57.3842, 30.8813}, {"R", 57.1591, 
     28.1642}, {"V", 63.0286, 32.2004}, {"Q", 54.774, 30.6936}, {"S", 
     56.898, 65.386}, {"K", 55.3617, 34.8906}, {"I", 60.4146, 
     40.4549}, {"G", 46.0692, 0}, {"S", 58.2961, 64.0659}, {"L", 53.904, 
     42.2776}};
 xticks = data[[All, 1]];
 ListLinePlot[Transpose[{Table[i, {i, 1, 37}], data[[All, 2]]}], 
    Axes -> False, Frame -> True, AspectRatio -> 0.4, ImageSize -> 750, FrameTicks -> {{{45, 50, 55, 60}, None}, {xticks, None}}]
```

But in the plot, no tick appears. Any suggestion will be really helpful. I am using Mathematica 12.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define `xticks` as

```
xticks = Thread[{Range@Length@data, data[[All, 1]]}];
```

[image]

**Note:** Replaced `Table[i, {i, 1, 37}]` with `Table[i, {i, 1, Length@data}]`

**See:** [Ticks > Details](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Ticks.html)

[image]